# Questions about the use of APNS

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications

We are building phonegap apps and we would like to send notifications to our users.

What is the cost for sending notifications ? Do we need only developer license or something else ?

Also, do we have to publish the apps in the app store in order to use APNS ? (We are building private business apps)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the cost for sending notifications ?

Zero, if you doenst use a third party service like [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/)

> Do we need only developer license or something else ?

Yes, without a license you cannot send any push notifications

> Also, do we have to publish the apps in the app store in order to use
>   APNS ?

No

Comment: Just to confirm, is this the program that we should apply for: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/ check out the comparison table. if you only need a developer account to send push notifications than all you need is a normal developer account (99$/year)

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add to the answer provided above. Not all third party services charge you for sending out push notification. [PushWoosh](http://pushwoosh.com/) is a free service without limits on the number of notifications being sent and the cost remains zero, unless you need some additional features (which you probably don't).